# Failed to start apache Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars

Tags: apache, ubuntu, localhost, apache2

I wanted to install httpd-2.2.32. So I downloaded it from this [link](https://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/) and installed it with the help of this [guid](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/07/install-apache-2-from-source-on-linux/).

It installed successfully and start it using this command,

```
sudo systemctl start apache2.service
```

but, I run below status command,

```
sudo systemctl status apache2.service
```

An error occurs as `Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars`

[image]

And localhost won't open

[image]

please help me to fix it

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Comment: I am facing same error but in EC2. please help.